# how to display the formula of a cell in another cell in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following formula in cell g4:

> =xirr(D3:D4,B3:B4)

this displays the value 1523% in cell g4

what I want to appear in cell g5 is this:

xirr(D3:D4,B3:B4)

But I don't want the formula to evaluate in cell g5. 
I just want to see the formula. 
And I do not want to have to write it out.
I am hoping I can copy and paste for multiple cells like this that I want to do.

here is my [spreadseet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gt-3vaitcDnIuEpJLB8NHgBjaifFjEs0S-0DTBBLMFM/edit?usp=sharing)
I am looking for a solution for excel or google spreadsheets, but I am hoping it can be applied to both.

Comment: The simplest solution would be a [vba] or [google-spreadsheet-api] UDF that returned the formula from the cell via the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) (or equivalent).

Comment: tks, but I did not want to use code in this instance.

Comment: OK, fair enough. In that case, there is no native worksheet formula to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I found this handy from excel help

> Switch between displaying formulas and their values on a worksheet
>   Press CTRL + ` (grave accent).

then I copied the cells I wanted nto notepad and removed the `=` at the start and replaced it with `'` this gave me something like `'xirr(D3:D4,B3:B4)` and then I pasted this into excel or google spreadsheets.

Comment: Did you need to add the 'tick' as the *Prefix Character* ? Without the equals, a formula is just text.

Comment: good point, `'` this is only needed if you want to show the = sign in the formula `'=xirr(D3:D4,B3:B4)` but otherwise `xirr(D3:D4,B3:B4)` will do without the `'` tks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is going to differ from [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) to [google-spreadsheets-api](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets-api) but the method will be similar. In VBA, the result can be returned with either the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx), [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527(v=office.12).aspx),  [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1Local property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838568.aspx) after checking the cell's [Range.HasFormula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837123.aspx).

The following is a User Defined Function¹ (aka UDF). See the footnote for implementation.

```
Function showFormula(rng As Range, _
                     Optional xlRefStyle As Variant, _
                     Optional bPFX As Boolean = False, _
                     Optional bLOC As Boolean = True)

    If IsMissing(xlRefStyle) Then
        xlRefStyle = Application.ReferenceStyle
    ElseIf xlRefStyle <> 1 Then
        xlRefStyle = xlR1C1
    End If

    If rng.Cells(1, 1).HasFormula Then
        Select Case xlRefStyle
            Case xlA1
                If bLOC Then
                    showFormula = _
                      Replace(rng.Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal, Chr(61), IIf(bPFX, Chr(61), vbNullString))
                Else
                    showFormula = _
                      Replace(rng.Cells(1, 1).Formula, Chr(61), IIf(bPFX, Chr(61), vbNullString))
                End If
            Case xlR1C1
                If bLOC Then
                    showFormula = _
                      Replace(rng.Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1Local, Chr(61), IIf(bPFX, Chr(61), vbNullString))
                Else
                    showFormula = _
                      Replace(rng.Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1, Chr(61), IIf(bPFX, Chr(61), vbNullString))
                End If
        End Select
    Else
        showFormula = vbNullString
    End If

End Function
```

Example of a [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) formula in B4.

[image: showFormula]
                    <sup>showFormula UDF syntax</sup>

On a system with German regional settings (and a DE-DE language version of Excel) the above would show as `SUMMEWENNS(B1:B3; A1:A3; "a")`.

[image: showFormula DE-DE]
                    <sup>showFormula UDF syntax in DE-DE system</sup>

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Comment: could not get this to work in excel, not sure why. when I was typing `showFormula` in the cell it was not showing up as a function to be used.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 the UDF has simply been put into the wrong place (e.g. right-click the worksheet name tab and View Code). See above for instructions on incorporating it to an Excel workbook.